# What is the name of the function that equals $1$ when argument rational and $0$ when irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

I vaguely remember that the real function defined as:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R: f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & : \text{$x$ is rational} \\ 0 & : \text {$x$ is irrational} \end{cases}$$

has a name attached to it, but I can't remember whose. Is it one of the Frenchmen whose names begin with L? I have a vague recollection but can't remember it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Dirichlet function.

Answer (score 3):

It is often referred to as [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function).